# Best practice to have multiple tableviews in a single view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

This question maybe already asked in stackoverflow. But, I did not get any clear idea to my scenario.

I have a viewcontroller (Say, MyViewController).

I have a scrollview(Say, MyScrollView) and I have N number of views (Say MyView1, MyView2, ...) in it.

Those views can be scrolled horizontally. Refer the below image for more clarification.

[image]

This image was taken from [here](https://github.com/TaPhuocHai/PHPageScrollView).

So, the red area is the scroll view that holds multiple views which are yellow color.

**Scenario:**

I want to call API's for each view, when the API calling and parsing data occurs, I need to show some loading activity indicator in the views. After successful parsing, I need to update corresponding view with UITableView.

**Questions:**

- In my case, the number of views may vary from 3 to 6. Should I maintain 6 separate UITableViews and UIActivityIndicator's?
- I tried with three pointers like left, middle & right to hold reference of tableview and activity indicator. But the problem is, before the first three pages are loading, if the user goes to the fourth view, this system will collapse with so many conditions.

Suggestions needed. Confused!!

Comment: I have some confusion about why are you using `UIScrollView` with in `UITableView`? I suggest to use `UICollectionView` In Horizontal style.

Comment: No, I have not use UIScrollView within UITableView. I have UIScrollView that contains multiple UIViews. Those each UIView's have each UITableView's in it.

Comment: Try using `UIPageViewController`, to which you can add multiple instance of view controller through data source methods. In your case, you can use a viewcontroller with tableview in it. And in datasource method of page controller you can pass instances of that view controller up to no.of pages. have a look at [this example](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use UIPageViewController with UITableView. it will solve your problem.